# NFC tag opening application to specific screen

Tags: android, nfc

From the research on NFC and opening applications I understand that they are capable of opening an app.  My question is can it open the app to a specific product page?

Like if I am at a store and I have an nfc tag placed in front of two products can I program each tag to open the app and go to the specific page for each product that would contain information about that particular product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a tag containing the URI http://www.example.com/myproduct1. Then you could register your product-specific activity "MyProduct1Activity" with the following intent filter:

```
<activity android:name=".MyProduct1Activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/myproduct1" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will cause the activity `MyProduct1Activity` to be started for tags that contain the URI http://www.example.com/myproduct1.

Alternatively, if multiple products share one activity, you could register a more generic intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
```

And retieve the intent within your activity using the activity's `getIntent()` method to parse the URI for the specific product.